# Winmerge & Excel csv

Tags: csv, tortoise-git, winmerge

I'm using TortoiseGit and I have a program that generates a csv file.

Basically when generating the same csv file again it will overwrite the old one. But when doing this, winmerge will show me that there has been a change in this csv file even though there is none.

It's a bit annoying. Is there a way to fix it ?

By the way, this works correctly when overwriting a normal .txt, .c or .cpp file.

[image]

Comment: there has been a change in this csv file even though there is none.    .......   Is there a date in the file that is causing the difference?  If so, it is not a WinMerge issue.

Comment: I got it. The difference had to do with CR and LF.

Answer (score 0):

You could ignore a few more compare categories?

```
Options -> Compare
```

[image]